# Can you explain this , challenge?

Tags: c, debugging, printf, puts

well let's see , i have this code of converting NFA automate to DFA ;which is written by me ; and i discovered let's say a "bug" ;

the printf() instruction

### which is meant to be like this " printf("",X); "  to prevent the bug

has no characters to print on the screen , you can use any argument you want ; even if it has no value .

the **problem** is when you remove one of these instructions the result turns upside down ( mingled displaying )

### challenge is : explain this bug with details !

the bug is in the NFAtoDFA() func line 69 & 75

here's the  code :

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #define max   50 //maximum number of symbols and states
    #define true  1
    #define false 0
    #define epsilon '~'

    char states [max]={'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','W'};
    char initState='0';
    char symbols[max]={epsilon,'a','b'};
    char finalStates[max]={'W'};
    char newSymbols[max]={'a','b'};
    char newStates[max][max];

    int nbrSymbols=3,nbrStates=11,nbrNewStates=0,nbrNewSymbols=0,nfaMaxLength=2,dfaMaxLength=0;

    char NFA [max] [max] [max];
    char DFA [max] [max] [max];
    int mm ;


    /** NDAtoDFA of the NFA */
    void NDAtoDFA();
        char *makeDFAstate  (char state[],int c);
            char *epClosure     (char stat);
            char *nextStates    (char sta,char symb);
            void  add_no_rpt    (char ss[],char aa[]);
            int   getCharIndex  (char str[],char c);
            int   accepted      (char str[],char toAccept[]) ;
        int   findDfaState  (char str[]);
    /*******************************/

    /** flag = 0 | 1         */
    /** keep ( 0 | 1 ) occurrences of char c in a string  */
    void del(char str[],char c,int flag);
    /******************************/


    /** printing Automates */
    void shift(int b,int a);
    void showNFA();
    void showDFA();
    int isFinalState(char state[]);
    /******************************/



    int main()
    {
        strcpy( NFA[0][0],"17");strcpy( NFA[1][0],"24");strcpy( NFA[2][1],"3");strcpy( NFA[3][0],"6");
        strcpy( NFA[4][2],"5");strcpy( NFA[5][0],"6");strcpy( NFA[6][0],"17");strcpy( NFA[7][1],"8");
        strcpy( NFA[8][2],"9");strcpy( NFA[9][2],"W");
        NDAtoDFA();
    }

    /******************************************************/

    /******************************************************/

    void NDAtoDFA()
    {
        int i,j;  char zz[max];
        strcpy(newSymbols,symbols);  del(newSymbols,epsilon,0);

        nbrNewSymbols=strlen(newSymbols);
        /** making the first state*/
        strcpy(newStates[nbrNewStates++], epClosure(initState) );
        /**                       */
                printf("",mm); /** <=== */
        for(i=0;i<nbrNewStates;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<nbrNewSymbols;j++)
            {
                strcpy(DFA[i][j],makeDFAstate(newStates[i],j));
                printf("",mm); /** <=== */
                if(findDfaState(DFA[i][j])==false) {strcpy(newStates[nbrNewStates++],DFA[i][j]);
                if(strlen(DFA[i][j])>dfaMaxLength) dfaMaxLength=strlen(DFA[i][j]);//for printing DFA
                }
            }
        }
        showNFA();
        printf("\n      ");shift(dfaMaxLength,0);  printf("[][][]");
        printf("\n      ");shift(dfaMaxLength,0);  printf("||  ||");
        printf("\n      ");shift(dfaMaxLength,0);  printf("||  ||");
        printf("\n      ");shift(dfaMaxLength,0);  printf("||  ||");
        printf("\n      ");shift(dfaMaxLength,0);  printf("||  ||");
        printf("\n      ");shift(dfaMaxLength,2);printf("[][]  [][]");
        printf("\n      ");shift(dfaMaxLength,2);printf(" \\\\    //");
        printf("\n      ");shift(dfaMaxLength,2);printf("  \\\\  // ");
        printf("\n      ");shift(dfaMaxLength,2);printf("   \\\\// ");
        printf("\n      ");shift(dfaMaxLength,2);printf("    \\/ ");
        showDFA();

    }
    /******************************************************/

    /******************************************************/

    void add_no_rpt(char ss[],char aa[])
    {int i,j;char tt[1];
        for (i=0;aa[i]!=0;i++) if(getCharIndex(ss,aa[i])==-1) {tt[0]=aa[i];tt[1]=0;strcat(ss,tt);}
    }
    /******************************************************/

    /******************************************************/

    void del(char str[],char c,int flag)
    {
        char * p,*barrier;
        barrier=p=strchr(str,c);
        if (flag==1)
            {
                barrier=p+1; //set the barrier after the first occurrence of c
                p=strchr(barrier,c);
            }
        while (p!=NULL)
         {
            for (;*p!='\0';p++) *p=*(p+1);
            p=strchr(barrier,c);
         }
    }

    /******************************************************/

    /******************************************************/

    char* nextStates (char sta,char symb)
    {   int i,j;
        for(i=0;i<nbrStates ;i++) if(sta ==states [i]) break;
        for(j=0;j<nbrSymbols;j++) if(symb==symbols[j]) break;
        return NFA[i][j];
    }
    /******************************************************/

    /******************************************************/

    int accepted (char str[],char toAccept[])
    {   int i;
        for (i = 0 ; toAccept[i]!=0; i++)
    {
        if(toAccept[i]==' ') {del(toAccept,toAccept[i],0);if(i!=0) i--;}
        if(getCharIndex(symbols,toAccept[i])!=-1 || getCharIndex(str,toAccept[i])==-1)  {return false;}
    }
    return true;
    }
    /******************************************************/

    /******************************************************/

    int getCharIndex(char str[],char c)
    {
        int i;
        for (i = 0 ; str[i]!=0; i++) if(str[i]==c) return i;
        return -1;
    }

    /******************************************************/

    /******************************************************/
    void showNFA()
    {int i,j;
                printf("\nSYMBOLS: %s\n",symbols);
                printf("STATES : %s\n",states);
                printf("FINAL STATES : %s\n\n",finalStates);
                puts("STATE TRANS.");
                printf("\n      ");shift(dfaMaxLength+2,4);printf("NFA | ");
                for (i = 0; i < nbrSymbols; i++) {printf("  %c", symbols[i]);shift(nfaMaxLength+1,0);}
                printf("\n ");shift(dfaMaxLength+2,0);printf("--------");
                for (i = 0; i < nbrSymbols; i++) for(j=0;j<nfaMaxLength+3;j++) printf("-"); printf("\n");
                for (i = 0; i < nbrStates; i++) {
                    shift(dfaMaxLength+3,0);
                    printf("  %c  | ",states[i]);
                    for (j = 0; j < nbrSymbols; j++)
                    {
                    if(strcmp(NFA[i][j],"")==0) {printf("  -");shift(nfaMaxLength+1,strlen(NFA[i][j]));}
                    else {printf("  %s",NFA[i][j]);shift(nfaMaxLength+2,strlen(NFA[i][j]));}
                    }
                    printf("\n");
                    }

    }
    /******************************************************/

    /******************************************************/

    void shift(int b,int a)
    {int i;
        for (i = 0; i < (b-a); i++)printf(" ");
    }
    /******************************************************/

    /******************************************************/
    void showDFA()
    {int i,j;
                printf("\n\n      ");shift(dfaMaxLength,5);printf("DFA    |");shift(5,0);
                for (i = 0; i < nbrNewSymbols; i++) {printf("%c", newSymbols[i]);shift(dfaMaxLength+5,0);}
                printf("\n     ");for(j=0;j<dfaMaxLength+6;j++)printf("-");
                for (i = 0; i < nbrNewSymbols; i++)for(j=0;j<dfaMaxLength+4;j++)printf("-"); printf("\n");
                for (i = 0; i<nbrNewStates; i++) {
                    if (isFinalState(newStates[i])==true)
                        if (i==0) printf(" <-> ");
                        else printf(" <-- ");
                    else
                        if (i==0) printf(" --> ");
                        else printf("     ");
                        printf("{%s}",newStates[i]);shift(dfaMaxLength,strlen(newStates[i]));printf(" |");
                    for (j = 0; j < nbrNewSymbols; j++)
                        printf("  {%s}  ",DFA[i][j]);
                         printf("\n");
                    }
    }
    /******************************************************/

    /******************************************************/

    char*epClosure(char stat)
    {   int i,j;char zz[max];
        zz[0] = stat;  zz[1]=0;
        for (i=0;zz[i]!=0;i++) add_no_rpt(zz,nextStates(zz[i],epsilon));
        return zz;
    }
    /******************************************************/

    /******************************************************/
    int findDfaState(char str[])
    {
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<nbrNewStates;i++)
        {
            if (accepted(newStates[i],str)==true && strlen(str)==strlen(newStates[i])) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    /******************************************************/

    /******************************************************/

    int isFinalState(char state[])
    {
        int i;
        for(i=0;state[i]!=0;i++) if (strchr(finalStates,state[i])!=NULL) return true;
         return false;
    }
    /******************************************************/

    /******************************************************/

    char *makeDFAstate(char state[],int c)
    {
         int i,j;char kk[max],yy[max];
         for (i=0;state[i]!=0;i++)
         {
             add_no_rpt(kk,nextStates(state[i],newSymbols[c]));
             j=strlen(kk)-1;
             add_no_rpt(kk,epClosure(kk[j]));
         }
         return kk;
    }
```

have fun !

Comment: You should see a compiler warning from that line. Did you read it?

Comment: yea i know , i don' want anything to be displayed , this instruction in particular prevented the bug , replace it with this if u want  => printf("",mm);

Comment: Take a look at the other warnings you're getting. They're probably related to the problem. Good code doesn't get any warnings.

Comment: only two warnings not related with this prblm !

F:\backup.c||In function 'epClosure':|
F:\backup.c|220|warning: function returns address of local variable [-Wreturn-local-addr]|
F:\backup.c||In function 'makeDFAstate':|
F:\backup.c|257|warning: function returns address of local variable [-Wreturn-local-addr]|
||=== Build finished: 0 error(s), 2 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|

Comment: How do you know they aren't related? They are undefined behavior that could cause anything to happen.

Comment: Hmm  i see , but in my mind there is something that says the printf or puts
function clears some area in the memory or a processor's register , that's why the result is correct when its used . don't you think it's bizarre in a way ?

Comment: They are buffered if that's what you mean. But printing nothing (even correctly) does not flush the buffers. Undefined behavior is undefined behavior. You can't rely on it doing what you want.

Comment: thanx man appreciate it . however this code is not my final work 
i've the final version done , with all your points taken care of already,
i just wanted to discuss  this problem & what are its causes , cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 functions `epClosure` and `makeDFAstate` that return addresses to local variables. This is undefined behavior and a likely cause to your problem.

To fix it either dynamically allocate memory (using `malloc`) for the variables or take an address to write to as an argument e.g. `void epClosure(char stat, char* buf)`. You'd probably want to also pass the size of the buffer to make sure you don't write past it.

Answer (score 0):

`puts(mm)` yields undefined behavior, because `mm` does not point to a string.

Comment: that's the point . remove the hole instruction then u can see the result !!

Comment: I did remove the instruction and I saw a result (and some warnings about returning a pointer to a local variable). but seeing the result was pure luck due two the other cases of undefined behavior.

Comment: Thank you sir , appreciate it :D